# Angularjs changing class on mouseenter (hover)

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following ng-repeat that displays a star whether or not `item.default` is equal to **true**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <i class="fa" ng-class="item.default == true ? 'fa-star' : 'fa-star-o'"></i>
</div>
```

I am using [fontawesome](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) and I wanted to do the following:

- If `item.default == false`, I wanted to remove the **fa-star-o** class and replace it with **fa-star** on a mouse hover (aka a full star if you are familiar with fontawesome).
- If `item.default == true`, don't do anything.

I'm knew to angular so I'm not quite sur how to accomplish this. I know I could usually create a `$scope` variable but since these are multiple items we are talking about, not sure how this can be done.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`ng-mouseenter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseenter), [`ng-mouseleave`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseleave) directives.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <i class="fa" 
         ng-class="{true:'fa-star' ,false: 'fa-star-o'}[item.default]"
         ng-mouseenter="item.default=true"
         ng-mouseleave="item.default=false"></i>
</div>
```

Since you are inside ng-repeat you could as well do:

```
<i class="fa" 
             ng-class="{true:'fa-star' ,false: 'fa-star-o'}[hovered]"
             ng-mouseenter="hovered=true"
             ng-mouseleave="hovered=false"></i>
```

With this you dont attach the property `hovered` on the `item` object instead on the child scope of `ng-repeat`, and for default state you could add the class `fa-star-o` on the element as well. If you want to make the behavior default always (when a property on the item is set to true) you could just do:

```
ng-class="{true:'fa-star' ,false: 'fa-star-o'}[hovered||item.default]"
```

Comment: Thanks PSL! The only thing I see being an issue is I don't want the class to change when `item.default` is **true** from the time the page loads. I guess I can do an ifthen inside the `ng-mouseenter`?

Comment: @bryan you mean to say that if item.default is true it will always remain as  `fa-star` even if you hovered? if so `{true:'fa-star' ,false: 'fa-star-o'}[hovered||item.default]`

Comment: yup, that is exactly what I mean

Comment: Thanks PSL, this worked perfectly! If you could find the time to explain what you have in `ng-class` that would really be awesome. I have no idea what is going on in that statement with the brackets...other than it works! haha

Comment: @PSL I did not know you could write the syntax like this with ng-class. Is this similar to using ternary operators?

Comment: @Mikey [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) provides that flexibility you could use an array and map as well apart from other expressions. Here is am just `OR` ing 2 values...

Comment: @bryan it is just an object literal evaluation expression as you would do `var obj = {true:'trueValue', false:'falseValue'}; var result = obj[expressionThatEvaluatesToTrueOrFalse]`. So in your case as long as item.default is true the result of the expression `hovered||item.default` will be true even if `hovered` is false and [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) on the object yields the value with respective to the key `"true"`.

Comment: @PsL Ok, yes I am surprised how many uses ng-class has. I always find new ones. But thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this way:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-init="displayStarAsSelected=[]">
    <i class="fa" 
         ng-init="displayStarAsSelected[$index]=item.default"
         ng-class="{'fa-star': displayStarAsSelected[$index], 'fa-star-o': !displayStarAsSelected[$index]}"
         ng-mouseenter="displayStarAsSelected[$index]=true"
         ng-mouseleave="displayStarAsSelected[$index]=item.default"></i>
</div>
```